# Getting segmentation fault while trying to use pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Swapping two nos. by the use of pointers.

```
int main()
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    a = 3;
    b = 5;
    *a=b;
    *b=a;
    printf("a=%d\n b=%d\n", *a, *b);
```

It is showing Segmentation fault at line "*a=b(7)"

I tried to introduce a new variable and assign it to *a and *b but it still shows  the same error.

Comment: If you don't see compilation errors for this code then fix your compiler options before doing anything else. It's a complete waste of time to run erroneous programs

Comment: "assigment to 'int*' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast."
this is the compilation error it gives

Comment: If you get a crash when assigning a value to `*a` what do you expect should happen if you introduce a new variable and do the same?

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error you are getting seems pretty descriptive.  "assigment to 'int*' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast." indicates that you are trying to assign an `int` to an `int *`, which is precisely what you are trying in the line `a = 3`.  If `a` were set to the address of an `int`, you could assign to it with `*a = 3`, and you could initialize `a` with something like `int x; int *a = &x;`, but writing `a = 3` is attempting to assign an `int` to an `int *`, which the compiler warns you about.

You are probably looking for something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    int *ap = &a;
    int *bp = &b;
    a = 3;
    b = 5;
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
    int tmp = a;
    *ap = b;
    *bp = tmp;
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```